# How does a voltage controller specifically L7805CV work ( detailed )?

Tags: voltage, transistors, voltage-regulator, power-electronics, electrical

I have used this vc in a project but for the file I'm not able to find any info on how this thing works like how and which transistors are in it. Anyone knowing anything about it please share.
Thank you.

Comment: Which part of proprietary is not understood?  Can you read  the schematic and understand it? In the spec http://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l78.pdf

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I was not able to understand the schematic in the PDF you attached. Is there any easier schematic or easier way to understand?

Comment: Did you understand the block diagram?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 very little

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I don't exactly know the function of those things.

Comment: This is similar and has a good explanation http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?baseLiteratureNumber=snva512&fileType=pdf  keep reading it until you understand it

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 That helped, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Does this simplified circuit help?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feSHpF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The specifics of the internals is basically the above and is published in the data-sheets. If you can't recognize common circuits in the actual 7805 schematic, and figure out the details of the complex internal circuitry, then I am afraid it is far too complicated to detail here.

There are numerous links already given in the comments here, and in the duplicate question, that will get you on your way though.